# Why is my jQuery hide and show function on the Form Select element only working in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created this form with several select menu and a couple of jQuery hide and show functions. The way the form is supposed to work is that, when you click on the options from the main select menu it sould autimatically show you the corresponding select submenu.
**Here is my code:**

**jQuery:**

```
    $("#mankleding").bind("click",menclothes);
    $("#manschoen").bind("click",menshoes);
    $("#manaccessoires").bind("click",menaccessoires);

    function menclothes(evt){

    $("#subkledingheren").show("fast");
    $("#subschoenenheren").hide("fast");
    $("#subsaccessoiresheren").hide("fast");
    }

    function menshoes(evt){

    $("#subkledingheren").hide("fast");
    $("#subschoenenheren").show("fast");
    $("#subsaccessoiresheren").hide("fast");
    }

    function menaccessoires(evt){

    $("#subkledingheren").hide("fast");
    $("#subschoenenheren").hide("fast");
    $("#subsaccessoiresheren").show("fast");

    }
```

**HTML:**

```
    <tr>
        <td> Artikel hoofd-categorie:   </td> <td> <select id="manhoofd">
                                <option>HEREN</option>
                                <option id="mankleding">KLEDING</option>
                                <option id="manschoen">SCHOENEN</option>
                                <option id="manaccessoires">ACCESSOIRES</option>
                               </select>
                              </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Artikel sub-categorie:     </td> <td id="subcategorie"> <select id="subkledingheren">
                                <option>HEREN-KLEDING</option>
                                <option>Broeken & Jeans</option>
                                <option>Jassen</option>
                                <option>Sweaters & Hoodies</option>
                                <option>Zwemkleding</option>
                               </select>

                               <select id="subschoenenheren">
                                <option>HEREN-SCHOENEN</option>
                                <option>Sneakers / Casual</option>
                                <option>Slippers & Sandalen</option>
                                <option>Instappers</option>
                               </select>

                               <select id="subsaccessoiresheren">
                                <option>HEREN-ACCESSOIRES</option>
                                <option>Horloges</option>
                                <option>Brillen & Zonnebrillen</option>
                                <option>Stropdassen</option>
                               </select>

                              </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Did you try all other browsers, Chrome, IE, Opera... Debugging? What does console say? Sure you're loading on doc ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `change` event:

```
$('#manhoofd').change(function(){
    var i = $('option:selected', this).text();
    $('select(:not(:first))').hide();
    $('select:contains('+i+')').show()          
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2a2S2/)

Comment: it works! I don't fully understand your code, could you explain your code i'm a jQuery novice.

Comment: @the_boy_za I'm a jQuery novice too, it selects the text of selected option - hides all the select elements except the first-one and shows the one that contains the word of the selected option. based on your markup I decided to use this solution.